# error Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magago.wishlist' doesn't exist magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9

i get this error after try login customer and process checkout like this

[image]

and i see report in var/report/718525705 like this

[image]

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed new magento??? Or you have upgraded it recently??? There is a table for wishlist which is not created that's what error is saying!!! Goto your mysql and check if wishlist table is there or not

Comment: i installed new magento 1.9.3. before i install it i add sample data  in database and install that magento.  in my database doesn't table wishlist. i don't know what i do next.

Comment: I will suggest you to do a reinstall. First do a reinstall and then install your sample data

Comment: You're welcum :)